# How to include files added to grid on form submit

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a form with fields and a grid.

```
{ textfield },
{ textfield },
{ textfield },
 etc...,
{ grid with toolbar: filefield }
```

On the grid, I have added a `filefield` toolbar which I have added a change listener to add the file to the grid:

```
addAttachment: function (field, value, eOpts) {
        var me = this,
            grid = field.up('grid'),
            gridStore = grid.getStore();
        gridStore.add(
            {
                filename: value,
                dateadded: new Date()
            });
    }
```

Basically, I want to add the attachments to the grid first so that I can send multiple files to the server. Is this possible?

Currently, doing `form.getValues()` only gets the other fields inside the form but not the toolbar. Getting the store items also doesn't seem to include the correct file paths as they are prefixed with `c:\fakepath\`.

What I want is to only push all form values including all the files which are stored in the grid on the `Save` event. Any luck guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Since, no one answered, here's what I've done:

First, instead of using a `filefield` in the tbar of the grid, I use a `button` instead. I've added a click listener to that button which adds a hidden `filefield` to the form:

```
addAttachment: function (button) {
    var me = this,
        form = button.up('form'),
        grid = button.up('grid'),
        gridStore = grid.getStore(),
        newFileField = {
            xtype: 'filefield',
            hidden: true,
            unused: true, //custom property to check if there is already an unused field
            listeners: {
                change: function (field, value, eOpts) {
                    gridStore.add(
                    {
                        filename: value,
                        dateadded: new Date()
                    });
                    field.unused = false;
                }
            }
        };

    //if there is already an unused field, we don't need to add a newField to the form
    if (!form.down('filefield[unused=true]')) {
        form.add(newFileField);
    }
    //imitate the filefield trigger. this will show the file dialog
    form.down('filefield[unused=true]').fileInputEl.dom.click();

}
```

So that's it. Basically, the `button` just imitates the `filefield` file dialog trigger but what actually happens is it adds a new `filefield` to the form. So calling `form.getForm().submit()` now includes all files which are also in the grid.

I hope this should help anyone in the future.

***CHEERS!***